# Hazelcast in memory data grid is very much slow compared to spring jpa

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

For our java project we are using hazelcast server and client model to cache data from database at the time of loading the application. 
This is my hazelcast.xml

```
<hazelcast>
<group>
    <name>dev</name>
    <password>dev-pass</password>
</group>
<management-center enabled="true">http://localhost:8080/mancenter</management-center>
<network>
    <port auto-increment="true">5701</port>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false"></multicast>
        <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <member>172.22.3.74</member>
            <!--<interface>127.0.0.1</interface>-->
        </tcp-ip>        </join>
    <interfaces enabled="false">
        <interface>10.10.1.*</interface>
    </interfaces>
    <symmetric-encryption enabled="false">           
        <algorithm>PBEWithMD5AndDES</algorithm>
        <!-- salt value to use when generating the secret key -->
        <salt>thesalt</salt>
        <!-- pass phrase to use when generating the secret key -->
        <password>thepass</password>
        <!-- iteration count to use when generating the secret key -->
        <iteration-count>19</iteration-count>
    </symmetric-encryption>
</network>
<properties>
    <property name="hazelcast.http.healthcheck.enabled">true</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.health.monitoring.delay.seconds">5</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.health.monitoring.level">NOISY</property>
</properties>


<map name="scripMasterMap">
    <near-cache name="default">
        <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
        <time-to-live-seconds>300</time-to-live-seconds>
        <max-idle-seconds>100</max-idle-seconds>
    </near-cache>       
    <backup-count>1</backup-count>       
    <time-to-live-seconds>8000</time-to-live-seconds>       
    <max-idle-seconds>3000</max-idle-seconds>       
    <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>       
    <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>       
    <merge-policy>hz.ADD_NEW_ENTRY</merge-policy>
</map>
```

Below is hazelcast server code.

RefData.java:

```
HazelcastInstance in = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
IMap<Integer, ScripMaster> map = in.getMap("scripMasterMap");
for(ScripMaster scripMaster: scripMasterService.getAllScripMasterList()) {
scripMasterMap.put(scripMaster.getAllToken(), scripMaster);
}
```

Below is hazelcast client code:

```
ClientConfig cl = new ClientConfig();
HazelcastInstance client = Hazelcast.newHazelcastClient(cl);
IMap<Object, Object> map = cl.getMap("scripMasterMap");
return map;
```

Below is my method which is returning data from hazelcast client map.

```
public Set<String> getAssetByInstrumentName(
   IMap<Integer, ScripMaster> map, String instrument) {

  Set<String> myset = new HashSet<String>();
  Predicate namePredicate = Predicates.equal("instrument", instrument);
  Collection<ScripMaster> assets = map.values(namePredicate );
  for(Iterator<ScripMaster> it = assets.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    ScripMaster scripmaster = it.next();
    myset.put(scripmaster.getAsset());
  }
  return myset;
}
```

This is straightforward code. Is there anything missing which needs to be done so that client can have the data from in memory?
This part is resolved now.

```
public Set<String> getAllCommodity(IMap<Integer, ScripMaster> map) {
Set<String> commoditySet = new HashSet<String>();
Aggregator<Map.Entry<Integer, ScripMaster>, Set<String>> aggregation = new CommodityAggregator();
PropertyExtractor<ScripMaster, String> propertyExtractor = new CommodityPropertyExtractor();
commoditySet = map.aggregate(aggregation);   
//        Aggregators.distinct("scripMaster.commodity");
//        Aggregators.distinct();
LOG.info("Number of commodities loaded::" + commoditySet.size());
return commoditySet;
}

public class CommodityAggregator extends Aggregator <Map.Entry<Integer, ScripMaster>, Set<String>> {

Set<String> commoditySet = new HashSet<String>();

@Override
public void accumulate(Map.Entry<Integer, ScripMaster> input) {

    commoditySet.add(input.getValue().getCommodity());
}

@Override
public void combine(Aggregator aggregator) {
}
@Override
public Set<String> aggregate() {
    return commoditySet;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add the hazelcast.xml content?

Comment: @noctarius i have added hazelcast.xml

Comment: Thanks, what kind of serialization do you use? How complex are the object trees? A good and fast serialization is vital to a system like Hazelcast as you have to serialize and deserialize all the time.

Comment: @noctarius Object tree(ScripMaster) is not so much complex. Currently we are using java.io.Serializable implementation.

Comment: The first step should be to exchange Java Serialization for pretty much anything else. I can recommend Kryo which can be used through a public from one of my colleagues: https://github.com/jerrinot/subzero

Comment: @noctarius I was using StreamSerializer for serialization, but no luck. It is taking a so much time to deserialize.

Comment: Do you have a running sample to show? Still sounds weird, I guess there's something wrong.

Comment: @noctarius Now model class implemented DataSerializable for serialization. writeData(ObjectDataOutput) and readData(ObjectDataOutput) methods has been overidden. Sequence is correct. Now I am getting java.io.utfdataformatexception: malformed byte sequence exception while client is trying to get the IMap.

Comment: @noctarius I was finally able to get data from map. I want the map to be refreshed automatically at server end when data changes in database and the same should be available at client end. For note my client is called at the application loading time and getting all data from nap.

Comment: You can use a continuous query cache to automatically update data onsite a client (when something changes on the members) but there's no direct way to automatically update the Hazelcast cluster when there are changes in the database (Hazelcast Striim can do it for specific databases by using the replication logs but not sure it works for your case: https://hazelcast.com/products/solutions/hazelcast-striim-hot-cache/)

Comment: @noctarius we will see that later. Now I want to get all distinct values of asset from map. Please see my updated post above.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on the instrument field.